# Disable continuous seeking while dragging seekbar on videojs

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, listener, video.js

I have a problem with videojs. In particular I have a problem with seekbar. In fact, as you can see in this example: http://videojs.com/advanced/ , the standard videojs seekbar has a problem with continuous seeking.

During dragging with mouse it seeks every single seconds, while in normal players (e.g. youtube) the video does the seeking just on mouse up event.

i'm trying to add a listener on my seekbar

```
 var SeekBar = videojs.getComponent('SeekBar');
```

but I have no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say 'no success', what do you mean more specifically?  (e.g. something to appear, or some certain state or value in the javascript code, etc)?  Please give a bit more detail.

Comment: I have no idea how to do what I need. I'm looking for advices.

Comment: @goltornate have you able to found any solution for this?

Comment: Any luck on this?